# Intent does not appear in Supported Intents

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, sirikit

Link to all the code I'm working with so far: https://github.com/banool/respose.

I want to make an app where it is possible for users to activate some intent it defines as an action in response to some event in the iOS shortcuts app. For example:

1. If I open app X.
2. Run intent from my app instead.

I've seen this done before in other apps, so I know it's possible.

I have an intent defined (see attached code as well as image) that seems to be correct as far as I can tell. I don't think I need an intent extension because I don't intend to handle the intent in the background or via Siri.

I notice that when I try to add an intent under `My Target -> General -> Supported Intents`, the dropdown doesn't show my intent, only the built in system intents.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I got to this point just by following the official guide from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app.

I don't think the fact that I'm using Flutter should matter so much right now (I figure that's more of a concern for when the app actually opens up from the shortcut), but perhaps I'm wrong.

I have registered the app on App Store connect and I'm using an identifier that has the sirikit capability enabled. I've also added the "Siri" capability in XCode. I've tried this on both a simulator and a real device, the results are the same.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image: xcode intent screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
It seems that you can just type the class name without prompt, and it should work just fine. Don't forget to select proper target though